# How to perform logging of forcefully exiting a running script?

Tags: perl, powershell, logging, exit

I have a powershell script that registers certain events and logs them to a file.

I want to be able to also log to that file the moment that the script was forcefully stopped. For example, by closing the window via X button.

How could I perform this?

We can include in the ecuation the following languages: Powershell via ConEmu console, Perl via ConEmu console, AutoIT.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick.

```
Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting -SupportEvent -Action `
{
    #action
}
```